# What's happening to my RockMongo (MongoDB GUI)?

Tags: php, mongodb

I just installed MongoDB 2008 Plus 2.6.1 in my Windows 8 64-bit laptop to work on a new project, but this is what my GUI looked like[image]

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: It looks like something is deprecated, isn't? What's your PHP version? What's the wamp version?

Comment: `The Mongo class is deprecated`. Googling. Simple.

Comment: @fmgonzalez I have WAMP 2.4 and PHP 5.4.12. Are they that old?

Comment: PHP 5.4 went end of life in September of 2015! It is beyond "that old".

Answer (score 4):

RockMongo doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. You'd rather use [robotomongo](http://robomongo.org/) or [humongous](http://humongous.io).

Answer (score 2):

Since RockMongo 1.1.5 hasn't been updated since 2012 you need to install an *older* PHP MongoDB driver (1.4.x and earlier) to match the older (and now fully deprecated) `Mongo` driver interface that RockMongo is expecting.

To force an install of the 1.4.5 PHP driver with PECL, use:

```
 pecl install -f mongo-1.4.5
```

Comment: I've raised an issue for this in the Rockmongo queue: ([#71](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/issues/71)) but the project doesn't appear to be actively maintained at the moment by the original author. There are [numerous forks](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/network) on Github but there doesn't appear to be an obvious "master" candidate.

Answer (score 1):

It just the [Mongo class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php) has been **DEPRECATED** as of version `1.3.0`.

Make sure you have installed latest [MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) and [RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com/downloads).

---

#### UPDATE

From [@Stennie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388319/stennie) :

> FYI, it is actually the opposite case: you need an older MongoDB driver, not the latest. Rockmongo 1.1.5 (currently the latest release available) hasn't been updated since end of 2012.

Thank you [@Stennie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388319/stennie) for your information.

I'm pretty sure the problem is, [@Gannicus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743334/gannicus) using **old RockMongo** and **MongoDB driver** `>= v1.5.0`.

- [`Mongo` class is deprecated](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/blob/61f72500b5eb9a2c07c53212b43c1678997358d6/app/models/MServer.php#L239) - (old RockMongo)
- [`Mongo::setSlaveOkay` is deprecated](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/blob/61f72500b5eb9a2c07c53212b43c1678997358d6/app/models/MServer.php#L240) - (old RockMongo)
- [`MongoCursor::$timeout` static property is deprecated](http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=mongo&version=1.5.0) - (PHP driver `>= v1.5.0`)

But, [@Stennie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388319/stennie) is right. Latest RockMongo is not compatible with PHP driver `>= v1.5.0`.

In this case, you need to install latest RockMongo and PHP driver `< v1.5.0`.

Comment: FYI, it is actually the opposite case: you need an older MongoDB driver, not the latest. Rockmongo 1.1.5 (currently the latest release available) hasn't been updated since end of 2012.